# neo4j not creating index on large dataset

Tags: neo4j

I am creating an index on a very large (8.2M node, 63M property) neo4j db instance.

`CREATE INDEX ON :Article(lowerTitle)`

It takes a negligible amount of time to issue the command, and the index (presumably) begins to process.

I have a max java heap of 100GB, and 40 cores (it's a large server). It is, however stupidly, a HDD.

Right after issuing the index command, my core usage spikes up to very efficient usage. After about 20 seconds, it drops to using almost no processor power, but about 90% of MEM.

I have left it running for 3 hours, and the index is still not created (or at least, there are no improvements for simple MATCH queries on single parameters, which average out at about 16 seconds).

`MATCH (arti {lowerTitle: "quantum mechanics"}) RETURN arti`

Is this reasonable? What is taking so long? Am I doing something wrong?

**NOTE: I have also noticed that my total database size (38.02GB) has not increased over the 3 hours**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For verifying that your index is online, issue the `:schema` command in the browser.

You should see your index status.

- ONLINE means OK
- POPULATING means it is still populating the indices
- FAILED means, well, failed

Your query will never run fast, because you are not using a label, so no indices will be used, change it to :

```
MATCH (arti:Article {lowerTitle: "quantum mechanics"}) RETURN arti
```